# How to set textstyle for specific words in a cell of Google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with default textstyle cell `A1`. I want to set a new text value to the cell with different textstyles:

```js
function setTextToCell (){
let comment = Browser.inputBox('Your comment');
let commentTextStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor('red');
  comment = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(comment).setTextStyle(commentTextStyle).build();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(`My comment - ${comment}`)


}
```

I expect to see default font color for `My comment -` and red for text from input box.

It's does not work. Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.setValue` only sets the value. To set rich text, use [`.setRichTextValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue). [Text style](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#settextstylestartoffset,-endoffset,-textstyle) should also be offseted as necessary.

#### Snippet:

```
richComment = SpreadsheetApp
    .newRichTextValue()
    .setText(`My comment - ${comment}`)// modified
    .setTextStyle(13, 13+comment.length-1, commentTextStyle)//modified
    .build();

SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getRange('A1')
  .setRichTextValue(richComment)//modified
```